# Building test environment inside Hyper-V - Adding machines into a Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, tcpip, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I am currently building a test environment with 4 servers inside Hyper-V.

One of the servers is a Domain Controller, the other servers will be a member of that domain.

All machines are on an internal hyper-V network, I have then set up the wireless network adapter on the host machine to allow the internal network to share this connection. This works fine and the machines can access the internet.

All machines have dynamic IP Addresses.

Now comes the problem: How do I get all the machines into the domain? Do I need to use static IP Addresses? Do I need to manually add them to the DNS? I will be setting up 2 of the machines in a NLB cluster will I need static ip addresses for that?

**Edit**

The ip address was being supplied by the DHCP allocator in the Internet Connection Sharing component of the wireless adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the Domain Controller to have a static IP and act as internal DHCP with itself as DNS, then the other computers use DNS to find the domain controller.

Now, the trick is: This is TOTALLY unrelated to Hyper-V. The absolutely same would apply to real machines. Please think your headlines through a little more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently it appears that Hyper-V is acting as a DHCP server. If one of the servers inside Hyper-V also has the DHCP role, will there be a conflict?

Comment: Hyper-V does NEVER act as a DHCP server. It does nto care about your network. If someone isntalled a DHCP server on the physical machine, that is not hyper-v acting as dhcp, but the dhcp server someone installed. Naturally thy will interfere. At this piont I would suggest reading the documentation how DHCP and DNS and Domains interact. You can also hardocde the static IP of the DC into the clients so they find the domain, or use forwarders in whatever dns they point to.

Comment: All the machines on the internal Hyper-V network are getting a 192 address, the host machine is on a 10 network. DNS, DHCP and default gateway are all set to 192.x.x.1

Comment: So do your job and find out why they get 192.* addresses. Some may be no addrese, autoconfigured due to missing DHCP. Sadly as you consider that confidentail I can not say....

Comment: Autoconfig should show up as a 169.254.*.* so they are getting it from somewhere else.  Double check with ipconfig /all, you may have more than one adapter, my own network we have VPNs on 10 and internal on 192.168 and a computer could hold on to address from both.